# Getting: index out of list error when trying to read text file

Tags: python

I am trying to extract all the float elements from dataset into three columns using Python. But I get an index out of range error.

```
#Reading the file line by line, separating each line by columns

file1=open("./Marine/bath.txt","r") 
x=[]                                  
y=[]
z=[]
i=1
for line in file1:   ### Reading sequencially the lines of the file1 object
    if i>4:
        columns=line.split()
        x.append(float(columns[3]))
        y.append(float(columns[1]))
        z.append(float(columns[5]))
    i=i+1

file1.close()

x=np.array(x)
y=np.array(y)
z=np.array(z)


print("Number of lines read                :",i-1)
print("Number of samples read from the file:",len(x))
```

Data looks like this:

```
zzzzzzz   50.0 ttttttt   329365.108 bbbbbbbb  4358562.104
zzzzzzz   220.00000000000003 ttttttt   402708.003 bbbbbbbb  4344547.635
zzzzzzz   110.00000000000001 ttttttt   347930.603 bbbbbbbb  4233132.610
```

with zzzzzzz   as the start of each line

Comment: I ain't able to reproduce the error. something is wrong with the text data.

Comment: thank you for looking into this for me. The data I posted was just for a few lines from the input text file. I notice however there are empty lines in the file which as pointed out may result in the error. I am new to the site, not sure how to upload relevant files.

Answer (score 2):

Your script works fine with the data you gave. The problem can most likely be found in the input file. If only one line in the file does not meet the data format (i.e. it has less than 6 columns, or maybe an empty line) one of the `columns[n]` statements trigger the index out of range error.

Comment: thank you, yes it does have some empty lines in the input file. Any recs on how to get the program to read non-empty lines only?

Comment: One possibility is that after you split the line with columns = line.split(), you can check the length of the column list. If len(columns) <> 6  and than handle accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This will do:  `[l for l in file.readlines() if l.strip()]`

---

```
file=open("text.txt","r")
file1 = [l for l in file.readlines() if l.strip()] #< --- Here


x=[]                                  
y=[]
z=[]
i=1
for line in file1:   ### Reading sequencially the lines of the file1 object
    if i>4:
        columns=line.split()
        x.append(float(columns[3]))
        y.append(float(columns[1]))
        z.append(float(columns[5]))
    i=i+1

file.close()

x=np.array(x)
y=np.array(y)
z=np.array(z)


print("Number of lines read                :",i-1)
print("Number of samples read from the file:",len(x))
```

---

```
Number of lines read                : 3
Number of samples read from the file: 0
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked for me. So does this code [l for l in file.readlines() if l.strip()] strip out all empty lines in the input text file. Do you have the syntax available so i can understand the arguments in here a bit more?

Comment: `l = '\n'; l.strip()` If you have this newline then strip will give you `''` if not (`l='any string'`) `l.strip()` will give you `'any string'` basically you are filtering  the lines which are not having new lines